On the vanishing coefficients of a Fourier series
Context: I just started Fourier series and I find it very interesting. It might be silly, but how do we know which Fourier coefficients are zero and which are not?
If I need to find the Fourier series representation of a function, how would I know which coefficients are zero without actually calculating all of them. Again I just started it and it would be helpful if someone could suggest some nice book which about Fourier series. I use the formula having complex numbers.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Each Fourier coefficient amounts to a particular definite integral, so this is essentially a question of why a particular integral is zero. Setting aside trigonometric polynomials (e.g., $f(x)=\cos 3x+\cos x$ only contains two Fourier modes and thus two nonzero coefficients) the reason is typically some kind of symmetry or periodicity in the function of interest. For instance, if $f(x)=-f(L-x)$ then only the Fourier sine coefficients can possibly be nonzero.
